# Connect to remote IP camera behind openvpn client

Tags: linux, routing, vpn, openvpn

I need remote connection (from "Client") to an ip camera behind openvpn client. The openvpn server runs on a public IP.

```
ip camera-------ASUS router---------Linux server----------Client
192.168.1.69    Openvpn client      Openvpn server        Openvpn client
                192.168.1.1         public ip x.y.z.k     Tun: 10.8.0.2
                Tun: 10.8.0.5       Tun:10.8.0.1
```

Openvpn client on Asus has this configuration:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote x.y.z.k 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
```

Openvpn server configuration:

```
local x.y.z.k
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 ipv6 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
persist-tun
```

Openvpn "client" configuration:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote x.y.z.k 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
```

How can "client" connect to the IP camera through the tunnel? Something is missing. Maybe need a port forwarding on the tunnel?

Behind Asus router there are other devices and I do not need to route their traffic through the VPN. Only ip camera has to use vpn tunnel.

"client" should address the camera via tunnel using a port, like `rtsp://10.8.0.5:7000`. In general there are more cameras and more "clients". Asus router has to forward the inbound request from 10.8.0.5:7000 to 192.168.1.69:554 and the video streaming from camera has to go into the tunnel to reach 10.8.0.2

Comment: You will need something like the **client-to-client** option in the server and tweak some iptables rules, this will allows you to each client to interact with each other... You can check out [here](https://backreference.org/2010/05/02/controlling-client-to-client-connections-in-openvpn/), maybe you get waht you need there

Comment: what about port forwarding on Asus router: 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.8.0.5 -p tcp --dport 7000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.69:554